# Abrir un Modal desde la URL (Link de una pagina a otra pagina)

Tags: bootstrap, modal, url

Soy nuevo en la comunidad y esta es mi primer pregunta para esta comunidad que me ha ayudado mucho.

He estado buscando como loco en español y en ingles como abrir un Modal de bootstrap 4 con la dirección URL de un href.

Quiero abrir el modal automaticamente desde el boton de una pagina a otra pagina. Tengo varios botones que deben abrir diferentes modales de la pagina destino.

No he podido encontrar algo que se le asemeje.

Saludos

Comment: Quieres que al presionar un link te lleve a otro con una modal abierta, no? Pasa una variable por get en tu cadena, y recupérala desde el otro lado de tu página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que me imagino que quieres hacer es usar un enlace `<a href="/nueva/url?modal=true">`. Si es así, yo utilizaría esta estrategia:

Utiliza la siguiente función de JavaScript que sirve para leer desde la URL cada variable que va después del símbolo `?`:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    let pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0].toUpperCase() == variable.toUpperCase()) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

y en la página de destino, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if (getQueryVariable("modal") == "true") {
        $("#tuModal").modal("show");
      }
    });
</script>
```

De esta manera, a través de la función `getQueryVariable` buscará el valor de `?modal=` y lo comparará con `true` (tú puedes personalizarlo como gustes) y, si se cumple esa condición, abrirá el modal una vez que la página esté lista ([`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)).

Comment: Gracias me sirvió perfecto... eso es lo que estaba buscando... No soy muy bueno en los script pero hice lo siguiente para poder abrir los demás modal de la pagina.

    <code>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (getQueryVariable("modal") == "0006") {
   $("#tratamiento6").modal("show");
    }
    if (getQueryVariable("modal") == "0007") {
   $("#tratamiento7").modal("show");
   }
  });
   </script>
    </code>

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer esto

**Pagina de donde mandas la petición**

```
<a href="otra_pagina.php?modal=true></a>
```

**Pagina donde quieres que se abra el modal**

**otra_pagina.php**

```
<script>
var open_modal = false;
open_modal = <?php _REQUEST['modal'];?>;
if (open_modal == true){
//Abre el modal que quieras
  $('#myModal').modal();
}
else{
//Si quiere poner algo aquí, ponlo
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nunca especificó que fuera en php, pero tu respuesta es buena

Comment: No creo que sea un gran problema cambiar la extensión del archivo